# google colab上で部分依存プロットをインポートできない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependenc
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_partial_dependence' from 'sklearn.inspection' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/inspection/__init__.py)
```

Comment: version 1.2 で `plot_partial_dependence` は廃止されたそうで [Individual Conditional Expectation plots](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_24_0.html#individual-conditional-expectation-plots)、`from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay` とするそうです。